# Add hyperlink in content of slider in CZML

Tags: javascript, jquery, cesiumjs, czml

I am working with CZML in Cesium 1.20.

I want to add a hyperlink to the slider text content.

I tried to put the content in slider as html link but it is displayed as plain text.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [`Entity.name`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html#name) for this.  The name accepts only plain text, not HTML.

Instead, add your description to [`Entity.description`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html#description).  The description appears in a [sandboxed iframe](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) under the name, and allows links and even JavaScript to execute within the confines of the sandbox.

Links should specify a target to escape the sandbox, for example `target="_top"` or `target="_blank"`.

Comment: thanks! that helped. It rendered link in entity.description. But now I want to change the camera view on click of it. But I am getting "Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set." when the link is clicked. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: Give this a try, but be careful not to allow end users to inject content into an un-sandboxed iframe.  `viewer.infoBox.frame.removeAttribute('sandbox');`

Comment: I tried this. Does not give error anymore. But does not execute alert written on onclick.

Comment: I don't think you can do alerts from within an iframe.  Try writing to the console instead.